# Why is the MAPE exceptionally high

Tags: machine-learning, keras, mape

```
error on test set: [2442.239337101689, 29.913345202693232, 5162219874.342154]
```

These are the results on the test test for a regression problem. The first two scores are MSE and MAE, and the last one is MAPE, how is this possible ?

As a side question which might help answer, my dataset contains a good number of examples where the "good" answer is 0. How does Keras deal with it when computing MAPE since a division by 0 would occur ?

Comment: I don't see how my question is unclear since Tim managed to answer it, my MAPE is probably very high because of epsilon parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Keras uses](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py)

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):

    diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                            K.epsilon(),
                                            None))

    return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
```

where `K.epsilon()` is a very small value. If you divide something, by something very small, you get a very big number.

If you have zeros [you should not use MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/35989) as error measure.